# Bug Datepicker Angular Material 1.1.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

http://codepen.io/Touhma/pen/qqvRzb

Why Is the datepicker Angular not working with 1.6.0 ?

I tried many thing but none are working ...; the initializer of the datepick just show me a whitescreen exactly like that :)
`

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-title>
    <md-card-title-text>
      <span class="md-headline">Maquette recherche</span>
    </md-card-title-text>
  </md-card-title>

  <md-card-actions layout="row"
                   layout-align="end center"
                   class="layout-align-end-center layout-row">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">

      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
      <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
        Lancer la recherche
      </md-tooltip>
    </md-button>
  </md-card-actions>

  <md-card-content>
    <md-content>
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="research.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material Datepicker is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317444/angular-material-datepicker-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the last release in Master fixes the issue:

[v1.1.1-master-0b72ab9](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/releases/tag/v1.1.1-master-0b72ab9)

Or

According to [#10168](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10168) set:

```
    $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
```