# Angular Material Datepicker is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am currently building a web application with Angular and I am using Angular Material for some UI components.
Currently, I have an issue that I can't resolve. When I use the datepicker like described on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker, the window opens but it stays empty.
[image]

Here's the code snippet for the datepicker.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="vm.registrationData.birthDate"
                                   md-placeholder="{{'start_register_birth_date' | translate}}"
                                   required></md-datepicker>
                    <div class="error-message"
                         ng-messages="registerForm.birthDate.$error"
                         ng-if="registerForm.birthDate.$touched && registerForm.birthDate.$invalid">
                        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                        <p ng-message="required">{{'start_register_error_birthDate_required' | translate}}</p>
                    </div>
```

Is there maybe something wrong with my imports?

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.min.js"></script>

<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle of this?

Comment: Do yo have console errors ?

Comment: No, there are no console errors. That was my first hope :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use an older version of Angular, say 1.5.9. Angular 1.6 disables prebinding of controllers.

See [Issue #10168](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10168) for more details. You can add

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
  });
```

if you insist on using Angular 1.6.

Comment: Wow, you just saved me several hours of trying to decipher a completely swallowed error.  Thank you!

Comment: thank you very much, is there any risk on enabling this?

Comment: @LexyFeito The risk would be that you enabling this will allow you to write controllers with bindings initialized in the constructor. In general, you shouldn't depend on this behavior. Those controllers will be break once you disable this flag.

Thus, if you enable this, I'd advise you to vigilant that you're not using any of your bindings in the constructor.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with angular. Where would I put this block of code?

Comment: @NeerajJain: Can you please tell us where to put this code?